# Adding information from variables to database PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add $_SESSION['user_id'] into a database and, when I echo it in this function, it works fine.  However, when I try to push it into my MySQL database, it adds the value 0.  Really confused as to why.  Thanks for any help!

```
function fill_team() {
    $i = 1;
    while ($i < 24) {
        $first_name = first_name();
        $last_name = second_name();
        echo "<br>";
        $add_names = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `players` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `user_id`) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '.$_SESSION['user_id']'.)");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to `return` in your `first_name()` and `second_name()` functions, instead of echo - just replace the `echo` with `return` and it should work.

Comment: Ah man, I had tried that but I must have done it with differing quotes.  Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing is if, to add the user id to the field `user_id` how do I add $_SESSION['user_id'].  It gives me the correct number if I echo it but if I add '.$_SESSION['user_id'].' it adds 0 to the database?

Comment: I think that should probably be a different question. If you can echo `$_SESSION['user_id']` and it gives the right result, you should also be able to use the value in SQL. If you add a new question and add in the code you've got that isn't working, I'll have a look.

Comment: I'll add it to this post, one moment

Comment: You're better off asking a separate question, as Dmitry's answer is now invalid. The problem you're getting now is because of quoting; you're using single quotes in the SQL string, as well as the PHP variable. You need to mark the variable up in curly brackets, like `{'$_SESSION['user_id']}')") (and you don't need the dots)

Comment: You can also echo out your SQL, and try to run it directly in the database - that will give you an idea if it's valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo $row2['first_name']`; with `return $row2['first_name'];`.
If you want to get some value from the function, you should use `return` operator to pass the value back. It has nothing to do with printing the value with `print` or `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

There's some messy mixed quoting inside the SQL statement:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `players` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `user_id`) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '.$_SESSION['user_id']'.)");
```

Off the top of my head, I have no idea what SQL this will produce, but this should be written as:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `players` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `user_id`) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$_SESSION[user_id]')");
```

or

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `players` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `user_id`) 
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."')");
```